# playing multiple mp3 files in a single page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a number of mp3 files in one page and I want to play mp3 files when clicked. How can I play them using jquery?

```
<a href="listen(1)" >play 1</a>
<a href="listen(2)" >play 2</a>
<a href="listen(3)" >play 3</a>
<a href="listen(4)" >play 4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
  // you have your mp3 file, play it
    // the way that you'd like
  var mp3 = $(this).prop('href');
});
```